# THREE.js LineSegments with multimaterial support

Tags: javascript, three.js, line-segment

In my project I am creating  `LineSegments` (LineMesh) with modified geometry (changing the vertex positions) from another mesh and with `MeshBasicMaterial`with black color.Adding the `LineMesh` to the already existing Mesh.
Everything works fine.
But now I want to hide particular part of the mesh by setting `visible` property to false by taking the `materialIndex` from the faces of geometry.But in this, the previously created mesh is hiding but `LineMesh` added to it is not hiding.
Is it possible to hide particular part of `LineMesh` and also wanted to know whether `LineMesh` will support `MultiMaterial`.So that it will be easy for me to apply `visibility`, `transparent` property to particular part of `Mesh`.

```
var mesh, renderer, scene, camera, materials;

init();
animate();

function init() {

// renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 300;
camera.lookAt( scene.position );

// directional
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
scene.add( light );

// ambient
var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
scene.add( ambient );

// geometry
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 4, 4, 4 );

// materials
materials = [
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide } )
];

// assign material to each face
for( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++ ) {
    geometry.faces[ i ].materialIndex = THREE.Math.randInt( 0, 1 );
}
geometry.sortFacesByMaterialIndex(); // optional, to reduce draw calls

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
scene.add( mesh );

mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000});
mesh2= new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, mat);
mesh.add(mesh2);

}

function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
mesh.rotation.z += 0.03;

renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

This below code is not to be working for LineSegments

```
mesh2= new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match your question. You say you're creating `LineSegments`, but the code says you're using `Line` and `LinePieces` (which is deprecated). I was also unable to get any lines to draw at all, even when I switched them to `LineSegments`, and added them directly to the scene without the box mesh. Please update your code to a current working example, and we'll be able to help debug further.

Comment: To be clear, I am having a JSON model having 2 material array for 2 different parts. I am using multimaterial to push these material information.With the help of material ID, I could turn on and off the part visibility. And also I would like to add LineSegments to the mesh.And now when I turn on off the part visibility, the line mesh is still on scene.And we could only control the visibility of LineMesh on a whole but not on a single part since it does not support multimaterial.

Comment: I have edited the post @TheJim01

Comment: What version of three.js are you using? `MultiMaterial` was recently deprecated in favor of a simple array. I'm not saying that upgrading will fix your problem (I haven't tried it myself--I'm currently on mobile), but  it might.

Comment: I am using THREE.js version 83 @TheJim01

Comment: Then how could it be solved ?

Comment: To my knowledge (and I'm honestly not that familiar with `Geometry`), `LineSegments` does not appear to support the concept of `materialIndex` like `Mesh` does, at least not from a `Geometry` type geometry object. If you switch to `BufferGeometry`, you can use [groups](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry.groups) to achieve what you want. If you're using `JSONLoader`, you could potentially modify it to use `BufferGeometry` directly.

Comment: It seems like line does not support BufferGeometry .

Comment: Both `Line` and `LineSegments` can take `BufferGeometry` as their geometry parameter.